# I am not able to understand the use of passing interface in generics in java

Tags: java

I am doing design pattern course from coursera and i am given an assignment of implementing empty block of code by observing the uml diagram. The given uml diagram is this.

[image]

This is given empty block of code that is given.

The `Program.java` source code follows.

```java
public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    // Make new empty "Study" playlist 
    Playlist studyPlaylist = new Playlist("Study");     

    // Make "Synth Pop" playlist and add 2 songs to it.
    Playlist synthPopPlaylist = new Playlist("Synth Pop");
    Song synthPopSong1 = new Song("Girl Like You", "Toro Y Moi" );
    Song synthPopSong2 = new Song("Outside", "TOPS");
    synthPopPlaylist.add(synthPopSong1);
    synthPopPlaylist.add(synthPopSong2);

    // Make "Experimental" playlist and add 3 songs to it, 
    // then set playback speed of the playlist to 0.5x
    Playlist experimentalPlaylist = new Playlist("Experimental");       
    Song experimentalSong1 = new Song("About you", "XXYYXX");
    Song experimentalSong2 = new Song("Motivation", "Clams Casino");    
    Song experimentalSong3 = new Song("Computer Vision", "Oneohtrix Point Never");
    experimentalPlaylist.add(experimentalSong1);
    experimentalPlaylist.add(experimentalSong2);
    experimentalPlaylist.add(experimentalSong3);
    float slowSpeed = 0.5f;
    experimentalPlaylist.setPlaybackSpeed(slowSpeed);
    
    // Add the "Synth Pop" playlist to the "Experimental" playlist
    experimentalPlaylist.add(synthPopPlaylist);

    // Add the "Experimental" playlist to the "Study" playlist
    studyPlaylist.add(experimentalPlaylist);

    // Create a new song and set its playback speed to 1.25x, play this song, 
    // get the name of glitchSong → "Textuell", then get the artist of this song → "Oval"
    Song glitchSong = new Song("Textuell", "Oval");
    float fasterSpeed = 1.25f;
    glitchSong.setPlaybackSpeed(fasterSpeed);
    glitchSong.play(); 
    String name = glitchSong.getName(); 
    String artist = glitchSong.getArtist(); 
    System.out.println ("The song name is " + name );
    System.out.println ("The song artist is " + artist );

    // Add glitchSong to the "Study" playlist
    studyPlaylist.add(glitchSong);

    // Play "Study" playlist.
    studyPlaylist.play(); 

    // Get the playlist name of studyPlaylist → "Study"
    System.out.println ("The Playlist's name is " + studyPlaylist.getName() );
    }
    }

    --------------------
    [IComponent.java]
    --------------------
    public interface IComponent {

    // Your code goes here!



    }

    --------------------
    [Playlist.java]
    --------------------
    public class Playlist implements IComponent {

    public String playlistName;
    public ArrayList<IComponent> playlist = new ArrayList();

    public Playlist(String playlistName) {
        this.playlistName = playlistName;
    }

    // Your code goes here!


    }

    --------------------
    [Song.java]
    --------------------
    public class Song implements IComponent {
    public String songName;
    public String artist;
    public float speed = 1; // Default playback speed

    public Song(String songName, String artist ) {
        this.songName = songName;
        this.artist = artist; 
    }
    
    // Your code goes here!
    
    }
```

In this block of code IComponent is interface and it is passed in the Arraylist generics, i am not able to understand what this block of code is signifying.

Comment: Basically this is saying that you have a list of objects, each of which can be used as an IComponent.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Having a List of objects in a container (List in this case) that all implement the same interface means you can call interface methods without knowing or caring what type of objects they are.

The generic list of components means all the objects in the list adhere to the `IComponent` interface. Since both `Song` and `Playlist` implement `IComponent` the list can contain both types of object.

As is that doesn't mean much as there are no methods declared in `IComponent`. After you declare your `play()` method in `IComponent` for example, the compiler will ensure that both `Song` and `Playlist` classes implement `play()`. That means when you get a reference to any object in the list you can call the `IComponent::play` method regardless of what type of object it is. If the object is a `Song`, the `Song::play` method is called. If it's a `Playlist` the `Playlist::play` method is called.

`Song::play` should of course, play the song.

The `Playlist::play` method should call `play()` on each `IComponent` in the list stored in the `Playlist`. Hence it's possible to have a `Playlist` contain another `Playlist` or any combination of songs and playlists.

Answer (score 0):

While your question dealt with a number of concepts (interfaces, composite pattern) your direct question was concerning the use of an interface as the specific type for a generic type in a declaration.

Consider the code:

```
List<IComponent> playlist = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is declaring a variable `playlist` as a list of IComponents. In other words, the list contains instances of classes that implement `IComponent`. In your case this means `playlist` can contain any instances of the `Song` and `Playlist` classes. However it is not limited to these classes: you define other classes (e.g. `VoiceMessage`) that could also implement `IComponent`.

By declaring the list as containing instances of `IComponent` you are expecting to limit the methods you call on the list items to those declared in that interface (though Java supports casting to avoid that limitation).